# Disabling Location Service through coding within app, when app is in background IOS

Tags: ios

I am new in IOS. I want to disable location service from code when our app in background. when it will come in foreground it should enable location.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: search applicationDidEnterInterInBackGround in AppDelegate, Inside this delegate method add [yourLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];.

Comment: Thanks Gagan for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

search applicationDidEnterInterInBackGround in AppDelegate, Inside this delegate method add `[yourLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation]`;

Similar way search for applicationWIllEnterForeground and add following code

```
[yourLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]
```